# Limit data input based on count of instances in table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers, oracle12c

Oracle 12c.

I currently have a table to hold patient visits containing a physician id, patient id, and data/time of visit.

I would like to create a constraint that, upon data entry, checks whether a specific physician has 5 appointments in that given day. If the physician does have 5 appointments, no additional appointment can be added.

Is there any way to do this other than using a stored procedure for entry?

If I were to use a stored procedure (as opposed to a trigger due issues declaring a variable) I receive the following error: Error(4,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; not null range default character

I am unsure if this is because I can't use a BEFORE UPDATE on a procedure. Any thoughts?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE doc_apt_limit_5
IS
v_visit_count
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON aa_patient_visit
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT (COUNT(*)) INTO v_visit_count
FROM aa_patient_visit
WHERE physid = :NEW.physid
GROUP BY physid, visittime;
IF v_visit_count > 4 THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'physician is fully booked     on     this date');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: A trigger seems a natural solutions, but it is basically the same idea.

Comment: I think this is probably a best route.. I tried doing it with a procedure since I was having trouble declaring a variable with my trigger, however receive an error. I've added this to my original post. 

Thanks again

Comment: Before (or after) is only for triggers, not procedures. Declaring a variable in a trigger isn't a problem. Trying to enforce this kind of constraint is though, due to concurrency (two inserts/updates at the same time can't see each other) unless you serialise somehow, and mutating table issues. This seems like an odd constraint anyway - number of appointments rather filled appointment slots.

Comment: Could you please expand on "rather filled appointment slots"? I am assuming that this would be a separate table in itself, however not sure how it would work.

Comment: I mean I would expect an appointment system to allocate patients to slots (time periods) for appointments, and to check they don't overlap (and maybe have a gap between if you're being fancy). Just counting them doesn't help much - they can overlap, and might be different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Go with trigger. Probably the best solution in this scenario.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER doc_apt_limit_5 BEFORE
  UPDATE OR
  INSERT ON aa_patient_visit FOR EACH ROW 
  DECLARE v_visit_count PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_visit_count
    FROM aa_patient_visit
    WHERE physid = :NEW.physid
    GROUP BY physid,
      visittime;
    IF v_visit_count > 4 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'physician is fully booked     on     this date');
    END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: How will you deal with simultaneous inserts/updates that can't see each other's changes? And mutating table errors?

Comment: @Alex: Lets go with statement level trigger than row level as illustrated.